How can i deal with cookie problems when developing a full stack application (Vue + Express.js)
When i developing a full stack application I use vue which host on port 5173 and express host on port 3000.
The problem i have is that I have no way of sending / saving the credentials in frontend to send to backend when developing. But this can be solved in production by building the frontend product and serve the frontend on app.get("*") Where the httpOnly cookie can be saved and send by the frontend. But this is really inconvinence when developing.
Thank you so much!
TLDR solution: I tried to build the project and serve the project on port 3000 in order for cookie to work.

Why not use a cookie on the frontend?

what do you mean by this? I have it to be httpOnly. where only the backend can access this one.

httponly isn't mentioned in the question. This is one of many reasons to use devserver proxy in FE, so BE would be available on the same origin. It's unknown what's your stack and whether this is feasible

Sorry for less clarification information inside this,
Frontend: I using npm create vue@latest. (Which use vite behind it).
I found a solution on the internet where i can put the proxy config inside vite.config.js in development. and in production I think it's recommend to use nginx reverse proxy to deal with the problem where the cookies not being saved).
Backend: I use node js express with app.use(cors());

`server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
location / {
    root /path/to/your/vue/app/dist;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location /api {
    proxy_pass http://api.example.com;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

}` something like this in vps production

do you use vite? Easy in vite to add a proxy for the API

It seems that you have found the solution. Consider answer it yourself and accept it instead of putting the solution in the question. This will help others to search more effectively.

I have solved my problem!
In development mode, you can add proxy https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html
And in production mode, you can configure nginx reverse proxy to deploy it /api -> api.example.com is an example.
